# Batch class String query does not allow a set filter

Tags: batch, querylocator

I am working on updating a batch class where I do a query for records and pass them to another class to handle the logic. I want to include a line where the record Id is not in a string set. (I am storing hardcoded ids in a custom setting that I split and add to a set which seems to be working) The problem is when I run the query in a test class it fails complaining about an unexpected token '{'. debug example with striped down fields:

```
23:57:44:273 USER_DEBUG [33]|DEBUG|Projected Query is:: SELECT Id, examplefield__c, examplefield__c FROM Revenue_Pipeline__c WHERE (examplefield__c = 'Booked' AND lookup__c NOT IN :{a1G000000000000000} AND FY_2018__c != 0)
```

How can I get the {} removed to correctly show the Id?

Example class:

```
global class NPD_Batch_BudgetToolLoad implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{
String versionFY;   
String versionId; 
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
Set<String> practiceFilter;
Map<String, Id> pStructureMap;   

public NPD_Batch_BudgetToolLoad(String versionId, String versionFY, Set<String> practiceFilter, Map<String, Id> pStructureMap, Date startDate, Date endDate) 
{
    this.versionFY = versionFY;
    this.versionId = versionId;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.practiceFilter = practiceFilter;
    this.pStructureMap = pStructureMap;
}       

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{
    String QUERY = getStringQuery(versionFY, practiceFilter);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(QUERY);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)  
{
    NPD_BudgetingDataLoad.createProjectedRevenue(scope, versionId, pStructureMap);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{

}

public String getStringQuery(String versionFY, Set<String> practiceFilter)
{
    String fyField = 'FY_' + versionFY + '__c != 0 ';
    String query =
    'SELECT Id,' +
            'CurrencyISOCode,' +
            'Account__c ' + 
    'FROM   Revenue_Pipeline__c ' +
    'WHERE  (NPD_Forecast_Category__c = \'Booked\' AND ' +
            'Product_Practice__c NOT IN :' + practiceFilter + ' AND ' +
            fyField)';
    return query;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing Apex bind variable syntax with string concatenation.

You need to change this line:

```
        'Product_Practice__c NOT IN :' + practiceFilter + ' AND ' +
```

to

```
        'Product_Practice__c NOT IN :practiceFilter AND ' +
```

*or* use something like `NOT IN (\'' + String.join(practiceFilter, '\', \'') + '\') AND '` to construct the list of Ids as a string for inclusion. Note that you can use simple binding in dynamic SOQL.

You've got some shadowing going on with parameters named the same thing as your instance variable `practiceFilter`, which you don't need to pass as a parameter to `getStringQuery()` because it's an instance variable. This may become problematic and confusing later on.